# Running a for loop for a list having multiple lists inside

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

Following this topic [bind_row datafrane within a list in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73159284/bind-row-datafrane-within-a-list-in-r/73159352#73159352) I would like to ask about doing a `for loop` for a list containing multiple lists.

```
#first list
x1 <- data.frame(rnorm(5), rnorm(5))
x2 <- data.frame(rnorm(5), rnorm(5))
x3 <- data.frame(rnorm(5), rnorm(5))

list1 <- list(x1,x2,x3)

#second list
x4 <- data.frame(rnorm(6), rnorm(6))
x5 <- data.frame(rnorm(6), rnorm(6))
x6 <- data.frame(rnorm(6), rnorm(6))

list2 <- list(x4,x5,x6)

#third list
x7 <- data.frame(rnorm(7), rnorm(7))
x8 <- data.frame(rnorm(7), rnorm(7))
x9 <- data.frame(rnorm(7), rnorm(7))

list3 <- list(x7,x8,x9)

biglist <- list(list1, list2,list3)
```

For single list (e.g. `list1`) I was trying to combine `x1` to `x2` and `x3` respectivelly using `for loop` with `bind_row` function like this:

```
df <- list()
for(i in 2:length(list1)){
  df[[i - 1]] <- dplyr::bind_rows(list1[[1]], list1[[i]])
}
```

I replicated this step for all lists I have by using this code follows

```
biglist1 <- list()
df <- list()

for(i in 1:length(biglist)){
  biglist1[[i]] <- biglist[[i]]
  for(j in 2:length(biglist1[[i]])) {
    df[[i]] <- bind_rows(biglist1[[i]][[1]], biglist1[[i]][[j]])
  }}
```

My desired output is to have a list having 4 lists that have 2 datafarmes. However, the output I got so far only have one dataframe. Anyone enlighten me please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: 4 * 2 != 9, which `x_` gets dropped and why?

Comment: @DonaldSeinen Hi, idk what you mean but my problem is that I would like to combine the first dataframe to two others. However, The output I got only showing the combination of `1st df` and `3rd df`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine the first element of a list with each of the others, we can use `lapply` like so

```
lapply(biglist, function(x){
    lapply(seq_along(x)[-1], function(i) {
        dplyr::bind_rows(x[[1]], x[[i]])
    })
})
```

Following the same logic, this can be re-written to a for loop:

```
out <- list()
for (i in seq_along(biglist)) {
    first <- biglist[[i]][[1]]
    l <- list()
    for (j in seq_along(biglist[[i]][-1])) {
        l[[j]] <- dplyr::bind_rows(first, biglist[[i]][[j + 1]])
    }
    out[[i]] <- l
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is almost there, but there was a few mistakes the indexing, and instead of the `df`-list, you'd want to make your `biglist1` into a `list-of-lists`, before applying the logic of your code from the single case. I.e.

```r
biglist1 <- list()

for (i in 1:length(biglist)) {
    
  biglist1[[i]] <- list()
  
  for(j in 2:length(biglist[[i]])) 
    biglist1[[i]][[j - 1]] <- bind_rows(biglist[[i]][[1]], biglist[[i]][[j]])
  
}
```

You could also simply wrap your for-loop into an `lapply` (as indicated by your tag) and return the `df` (or go the full way as described by @Donald Seinen with two times `lapply`):

```r
lapply(biglist, \(list1) {
                          df <- list()
                          for (i in 2:length(list1))
                            df[[i - 1]] <- dplyr::bind_rows(list1[[1]], list1[[i]])
                          return(df)
                          }
       )
```

Comment: Hi @harre, the ``lapply` function worked well. However, the `for loop` here I think need to be review because it got the error: `Error in `*tmp*`[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
`

Comment: Sorry, yes a typo [[1]] instead of [[i]]. Corrected.